# How to use javascript filter function

Tags: javascript

I am running the code below in chrome's console.  I would like filteredArr to contain 3 objects however I am getting the empty {} as a fourth. The idea is to filter through the flags array and return objects with key == true(or === true - not sure which one works) and the values of true keys append to filteredArr.  Any help is appreciated!

```
var flags = [ { usa: ["red", "white", "blue"] }, null, { germany: ["red", "yellow", "black"] }, {}, { jamaica: ["green", "yellow", "black"] }, "", undefined];

var filteredArr = flags.filter(function(val) {

    return !(val === "" || typeof val == "undefined" || val === null || typeof val == "null");
});
```

filteredArr;

Comment: this code almost gives me a headache.

Comment: `typeof val == "null"` can be removed since `typeof null === "object"`

Comment: Is this what you need `.filter(function(val){return !!val && Object.keys(val).length})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you want to filter falsy bits, filter on `Boolean`:

```
var filteredArr = flags.filter(Boolean)
```

Which produces the same result as your code but more elegantly. Now if you want to filter objects without enumerable keys you can use Object.keys:

```
var filteredArr = flags.filter(Boolean).
                        filter(function(el){ return Object.keys(el).length })
```

Alternatively:

```
var filteredArr = flags.map(Object).
                        filter(function(x){ return Object.keys(x).length })
```

Or, flattened into a single filter:

```
var filtered =  flags.filter(function(x){ return Object.keys(Object(x)).length })
```

Comment: Ah, beat me by one sec.

Comment: I know its trivial in this example, but each filter is going to loop through the list right? basically twice...

Comment: @elclanrs Sorry, happens to me all the time too. Thanks for the edit :)

Comment: @PSL Yes. Though in terms of performance, it would be advisable to use a `for` loop rather than `.filter` since no engines will optimize that closure away which is expensive here. In terms of iteration count - with the current implementation it will iterate the list twice, however in future versions there will be ways around it (cast into a generator - then chain to generators, effectively iterating the array zero times and performing no actions until it is iterated).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum that will be awesome.. :)

Comment: `flags.filter(function(x){ return Object.keys(Object(x)).length })` would do that trick sort-of. I just find it less elegant @elclanrs

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: yeah, it wouldn't have worked anyway, as it returns booleans, it doesn't compose, but yes, that would be better. I would just do that instead of going for `for` loop if I worry about performance.

Comment: I used the flattened into a single filter option.  You all are great!

Answer (score 0):

An empty object is not null. You'll need to check if an object is empty via something like this:

```
Object.keys(obj).length === 0
```